# Insert data into a different column when copying from one table to another in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am using an AFTER INSERT row trigger in Oracle 11g to copy specific columns from one table to another on insert.   I have the trigger and insert working ok.   The problem I have is that I need to insert the new data from one column to a different column when copying it.

The trigger info reads:

```
BEGIN
 insert into BALES_STORAGE 
               (CROP, 
               CUTTING, 
               DESTINATION, 
               BALES_MOVED, 
               DATE_MOVED, 
               PASTURE, 
               TARGET_LB_PER_DAY)
 values 
               (:new.CROP, 
               :new.CUTTING, 
               :new.MOVING_LOCATION, 
               :new.BALES_MOVED, 
               :new.DATE_MOVED, 
               :new.PASTURE, 
               :new.TARGET_LB_PER_DAY);
END;
```

The first table is called "BALES_HARVESTED" and the 2nd table the trigger inserts the selected columns into is called "BALES_STORAGE". I need to insert the :new.MOVING_LOCATION data into the column called DESTINATION on the second table.

So my question is: when using an after insert row trigger, how to I change the column that the data is inserted into?

Thanks for any help.

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger code worked just fine for me.  Not sure what the problem is.  The 3rd column in your `INSERT` statement does the column mapping correctly.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d2fd5/1/1

Maybe you have different structures or foreign key constraints. Could you elaborate on what error you get?  Does it produce an ORA- error? or does it simply not produce the desired result, but no error?